# drupal_is_front_page can't recognize arguments

Tags: views

I have a view display as a drupal site's front page. And that view has a path (like **"/myview"**. Also that view takes several arguments from url (like **"/myview/arg1/arg2"**). I also have some extra code to be called on the front page only. But it seams that drupal_is_front_page function can't recognize a view page with arguments as a front page. For example, drupal_is_front_page returns:

- 1) "mysite.com/" - >true
- 2) "mysite.com/myview/" - >true
- 3) "mysite.com/myview/arg1" - >**false**
- 4) "mysite.com/myview/any-text-here" ->**false**

In any of these cases a view display returns correct data, but drupal_is_front_page - not. Is there any way to check if its a frontpage in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the [drupal_is_front_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7.x) function you see it performs a check on

```
($_GET['q'] == variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node'));
```

So it only returns true if there is an exact match.

You can recreate the function and use something this instead, to check if the frontpage url is a part of the request url:

```
(strpos($_GET['q'], variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node')) !== false)
```

All other code in drupal_is_front_page is for static caching. You want to copy that if you intend to call this function often. If it is for one check you can do with this simple function:

```
function drupal_is_front_page2() {
  $is_front_page = (strpos($_GET['q'], variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node')) !== false);
  return $is_front_page;
}
```